# Functions responsibility on data in C

Tags: c++, c

Recently I ran into a problem at work where you have two functions; one opens a file descriptor (which is a local variable in the function), and passes it to another function where it is used for reading or writing. Now, when one of the operations read/write fails the function that was doing the read/write closes this file descriptor, and returns.
The question is, whose responsibility is to close the file descriptor, or let's say do cleanup:

1. the function which created the fd
2. the function which experienced the error while read/write

Is there a design rule for these kind of cases; let's say creation and cleanup.

BTW, the problem was that both functions attempted to close the fd, which resulted in a crash on the second call to close.

Comment: Just write it into the contract of those functions who has ownership of the file handle at any given time. PS: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: If you *must* pass `fd` from one function to another and either one may close it, just have it set to NULL as well. And don't forget to first test before using `fclose`. But the easiest way is probably to avoid the problem - why *close* the file inside a function if an error occured? Even if you prefer that, if it does error out, why not communicate that back to the caller?

Comment: @Jongware: file descriptors are small(ish) integers; setting to NULL is inappropriate, but -1 might be sensible.  OTOH, file descriptors are seldom passed as a pointer to `int`, so the change would seldom be reflected in the calling code.

Comment: Generally, the function that opened the file should close it; the function that experienced the error should report the error, but not close the file.  However, you can work it how you like as long as the contract is documented and enforced — the calling code needs to know when the called code closed the file to avoid double closes.  Are you sure you're using file descriptors and not `FILE *` (file streams)?  It's unlikely that closing a file descriptor twice would cause a crash (error, yes, but not a crash).  OTOH, calling `fclose()` on an already closed file stream could cause problems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yeah sorry - I'm way too much wedded to `FILE *` So please mentally `s/fclose/close/`. I'm actually surprised to read that `fclose` on a NULL pointer or already-closed file is actually undefined behavior, rather than "ignored" or returning a clear error - is that also true for `close`?

Comment: @Jongware: Using `close()` with a bad (closed or never valid) file descriptor generates -1 as the return value and sets `errno` to EBADF usually.  No danger of crashing because there are no pointers involved.  Even with file streams, you seldom pass a `FILE **` to a function, so the called function still couldn't affect the `FILE *` value in the calling function.  As I outlined in another comment, the code has to be careful if the called function closes the file — it is usually best if it does not, but as long as everyone knows what's happening, it isn't absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer — the general design issue and the detailed mechanics for your situation.

#### General Design

Handling resources such as file descriptors correctly, and making sure they are released correctly, is an important design issue.  There are multiple ways to manage the problem that work.  There are some others that don't.

Your tags use C and C++; be aware that C++ has extra mechanisms available to it.

In C++, the RAII — Resource Acquisition Is Initialization — idiom is a great help.  When you acquire a resource, you ensure that whatever acquires the resource initializes a value that will be properly destructed and will release the resource when destructed.

In both languages, it is generally best if the function responsible for allocating the resource also releases it.  If a function opens a file, it should close it.  If a function is given an open file, it should not close the file.

In the comments, I wrote:

> Generally, the function that opened the file should close it; the function that experienced the error should report the error, but not close the file. However, you can work it how you like as long as the contract is documented and enforced — the calling code needs to know when the called code closed the file to avoid double closes.

It would generally be a bad design for the called function to close the file sometimes (on error), but not other times (no error).  If you must go that way, then it is crucial that the calling function is informed that the file is closed; the called function must return an error indication that tells the calling code that the file is no longer valid and should neither be used nor closed.  As long as the information is relayed and handled, there isn't a problem — but the functions are harder to use.

Note that if a function is designed to return an opened resource (it is a function that's responsible for opening a file and making it available to the function that called it), then the responsibility for closing the file falls on the code that calls the opening function.  That is a legitimate design; you just have to make sure that there is a function that knows how to close it, and that the calling code does close it.

Similar comments apply to memory allocation.  If a function allocates memory, you must know when the memory will be freed, and ensure that it is freed.  If it was allocated for the purposes of the current function and functions it calls, then the memory should be released before return.  If it was allocated for use by the calling functions, then the responsibility for release transfers to the calling functions.

#### Detailed mechanics

Are you sure you're using file descriptors and not `FILE *` (file streams)? It's unlikely that closing a file descriptor twice would cause a crash (error, yes, but not a crash). OTOH, calling `fclose()` on an already closed file stream could cause problems.

In general, in C, you pass file descriptors, which a small integers, by value, so there isn't a way to tell the calling function that the file descriptor is no longer valid.  In C++, you could pass them by reference, though it is not conventional to do so.  Similarly with `FILE *`; they're most usually passed by value, not by reference, so there isn't a way to tell the calling code that the file is not usable any more by modifying the value passed to the function.

You can invalidate a file descriptor by setting it to `-1`; that is never a valid file descriptor.  Using `0` is a bad idea; it is equivalent to using standard input.  You can invalidate a file stream by setting it to `0` (aka `NULL`).  Passing the null pointer to functions that try to use the file stream will tend to cause crashes.  Passing an invalid file descriptor typically won't cause crashes — the calls may fail with `EBADF` set in `errno`, but that's the limit of the damage, usually.

Using file descriptors, you will seldom get a crash because the file descriptor is no longer valid.  Using file streams, all sorts of things can go wrong if you try using an invalid file stream pointer.